# ZF3 - ZfcUser cant take identity from session

Tags: zend-framework3

I have very strange problem. I use ZfcUser as authentication module. I made a lot of projects on lot of different environments using ZF3 and ZfcUser module. I have nevere experienced such kind of problem which I will explain bellow. In my current project I cant login into system on production server. I succesfuly log from local env, or other test environments.

I try to investigate whats going on. I went to login page on production, entered my credentials and system redirects me to home page. No errors, no warnings... notihnig. But I was not logged in. I check the identity from the framework (identity()) - it was null. I thought that may be it is server issue with the php sessions. I checked the sessions on server. It appears that the problem was not there.

The framework succesfully stored the data it needs in sessions. I found the Zend_Auth key, the identity key and the value for logged user. It seems that with php sessions everything is OK.

I am powerless and cant even think about what is going on here and where is the problem. No errors are thrown. I trace the execution of code on local and production environment. Everything is same. The frameworks seems to work properly. But the IDENTITY is allways null

Comment: Did you try after clearing cache?

Comment: Ofcourse I tried cleaning cache, cookies.... 

Finaly I found that Chrome is the reason. On Firefox and Opera everything works well. I even thinkging of migrating to firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

So, the site was runing under a subdomain. Let say **sub.domain.tld**. This site is different from main domain which is **domain.tld**. In the programm code, the favicon of application was requested form the **domain.tld** not from the **sub.domain.tld**.

As a result when you hit the http://sub.domain.tld the browser stores two PHPSESSID cookies. One under **sub.domain** and another under **domain.tld** which couses Chrome to messed up

Interesting is that, Firefox and IE didnt messed with the sessions and the site was working porperly. I dont say that Crhome is guilty. Obviously the programm code was cousing the problem. But Chrome recognize that one domain is sub domain of the other

Thats why, when I was trying to run project on different environments as local setup or different domain e.g. **test.different-domain.tld**, ther were again two PHPSESSID cookies set, but in this time Chrome didnt messed up with the sessions becouse **test.different-domain.tld** is not recognized as subdomain of **domain.tld**

Very small and silly mistake, but cousing big problems